# How to call a function when drop down list in gridview is changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and for one of the columns I'm using a drop down list that displays a list of users:

```
<asp:GridView  style="float:left"  
    ID="gvBookings" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    CssClass="tblResults" 
    runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvBookings_RowDataBound"                           
    DataKeyField="ID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    allowpaging="false"
             <Columns>       
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FinishDate" HeaderText="Finish Date"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Spent By">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList id="ddlUsers" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind I need to call a function that updates the database when the drop down list is changed. I have done this already for the `FinishDate` column so is there a similar way to do this for the drop down menu?

Code behind:

```
protected void gvBookings_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        BHTaskClass.BookingTask booking = (BHTaskClass.BookingTask)e.Row.DataItem;
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
             {
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    string FinishTime = booking.FinishTime.HasValue ? booking.FinishTime.Value.ToString("hh':'mm") : "";
                    c.Text = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtFinishTime" + booking.ID + "\" style=\"width:70px\" type=\"text\" onblur=\"UpdateFinishTime(" + booking.ID + ",this.value)\"   value=\"" + FinishTime + "\" >";
                }
                if (count == 2) 
                {
                    ddlUsers.SelectedValue = booking.TimeSpentName;
                }
                     count++;
             }
         }
    }
```

So when the `FinishDate` textbox is changed it calls the `UpdateFinishTime` function and this updates the database. How do I call a function for the drop down list?

Answer (score 1):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlUsers" runat="server" 
       AutoPostBack="true" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="YourFunction_Changed">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void YourFunction_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff...
}
```

Comment: How do I get the row ID?

Comment: @user123456789 Ask one question per post. One way to do it which is probably not the optimal is to Create Custom DropDown which inherits the DropDown and have CommandArguemnt property. After that on item bound of your grid you are finding the ddl control and setting the command argument to the ID of the row. If you want to search for more optimal way you can ask another question like I said one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Row ID you can do it as below

```
protected void YourFunction_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do stuff...
   int Index = ((GridViewRow)((sender as Control)).NamingContainer).RowIndex;

  // your logic follows based on the Index 
}
```